# .service or crontab for shell script calling python-CLI app and/or python script failing

Tags: boot, cron, midi, systemd-unit

This isn't necessarily a Pi-specific question, but might be applicable to general Linux. However, my hunch is that the Pi's uniqueness might have something to do with it.

I'm trying to run two scripts on startup on my Pi 4 (raspbian stretch).
One is a python 2 script (I have Python 2 and 3 installed on the Pi, but Python2.7 is run when you simply do `python script.py`), the other is a CLI app based on a python 3 module installed via pip3, `midiroute`. **EDIT**: The purpose of running both of these scripts at startup: 1) to start the [samplerbox script](https://homspace.nl/samplerbox/) , and 2) to loopback incoming midi from an attached Midi keyboard (native instruments komplete kontrol) back to its 5-pin output, if the keyboard is connected and listed as a midi device. Context: this allows me to control hardware connected via 5-pin midi as well as the software instrument that is samplerbox.

I remember having this issue before (in a different context, on an Ubuntu server), so I tried to find the full paths to the binaries that execute these scripts using

```
which python
which midiroute
```

This returns the full paths.

I then put these full paths into either crontab or a new `.service` file. However, when aiming to run them on startup, neither work.

The py script tells me it's missing a required module (which it isn't if i simply start the script using `python script.py`), like so:

```
  File "/home/pi/SamplerBox/samplerbox.py", line 27, in <module>
    import samplerbox_audio   # audio-module (cython)
  File "samplerbox_audio.pyx", line 51, in init samplerbox_audio
    import gv
ImportError: No module named gv
```

The other job logs an error that it can't find the required binary, like so: `/home/pi/nl_utils/midi_redirect_kompletekontrol.sh: 7: /home/pi/nl_utils/midi_redirect_kompletekontrol.sh: midiroute: not found`

any ideas as to how I can do this?

#### EDIT:

my crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/SamplerBox/samplerbox.py > /home/pi/nl_utils/logfiles/samplerbox.log 2>&1
@reboot sh /home/pi/nl_utils/midi_redirect_kompletekontrol.sh > /home/pi/nl_utils/logfiles/midi_route.log 2>&1
```

my `.service`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/systemd/system $ cat run_midi_routing_at_startup.service
[Unit]
Description=Run the midi routing script after startup once all other startup daemons have loaded.
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/pi/nl_utils/midi_redirect_kompletekontrol.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: You could help yourself by editing your question to add the lines from your `crontab`. ALSO: In general, if you can run something successfully from the command line, then you can also run it from `cron`. So - can you successfully run these scripts from the CLI? I've got a couple of hunches re the cause for your issue - I'll try to answer once you reply here.

Comment: you're right, apologies. i figured it'd be a dead simple one so wasn't as thorough as i should have been. i'll upate the Q tomorrow, i've packed up my Pi rn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities that come to mind:

1. By using `which python`, you may have taken the incorrect path for the script that uses Python3. You will need to use the appropriate full path for Python 3; e.g. `usr/bin/python3`. The following cmd will show what's available:

   ```
   ls -l /usr/bin | grep python
   ```

   > NOTE: If you want to change which version of Python is used as the ***default*** on your system, use the `update-alternatives` command. Here's [an example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118802/83790) of how `update-alternatives` is used.
2. If your script runs successfully from the command line/interactive shell, but fails silently when run under `@reboot` in your `crontab` - or in a `systemd unit`, the cause may be a *dependency issue*. By that, I mean only that when (for example) `cron` tries to run your `@reboot` script, the *init* system (`systemd` for recent RPi OS) may not have yet started it. For example: your script calls for a network connection, but the network has not yet been initialized during the boot process.

   In `cron`, this can often be cured by inserting a `sleep` command in front of your script call. This simply postpones the start time of your objective script by a few seconds, giving the *init* system time to get all other services started.

   In a `systemd unit`, one or more predicates (e.g. `After=...`) can be added to your unit file that will ensure it's not started until a required service is available.

   Another *symptom* to check is for a script that runs successfully from the CLI but fails when run as a `cron` job. This *symptom* suggests that the failure is due to the substantial differences between the CLI user's rich **environment** in an interactive shell, and the austere **environment** in `cron`.
3. Other issues:

   If the suggestions above don't cure your issue, more details in your question may be needed. You should consider adding a ***redirect*** in your `crontab` to capture any errors generated. A general form four your `@reboot` entry could be as follows:

   ```
   @reboot sleep 30; /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/myscript.py >> /path/to/mylog 2>&1
   ```

Comment: hi there, thanks for your answer. as you can see in my edit, i suppose i took **1.** and **3** as read, it would have been useful for me to specify them from the get-go. I wasn't aware of `sleep`, however, unfortunately that didn't fix my crontab -- I'm still getting the same errors, namely a missing module `gv` in the python script and a missing app `midiroute` in the second script. To reiterate, both of these work in an interactive shell

Comment: @nikUoM: I'm not sure I understand your comment wrt `i took 1. and 3 as read...`. Moving on, the new data suggests that the issue may be a difference in the **environment**. Were you aware that your interactive shell & `cron` have vastly different set of env variables? Verify by running `printenv` fm the CLI, then run `printenv` in a `cron` job: `* * * * *  printenv > /home/pi/cronenv.txt 2>&1`. Find the env var that is *peculiar* to your scripts, or [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)

Comment: my comment means, yes you need to redirect your output, and yes, you need to put the full path in there, but i thought the knowledge of these facts was implied in the way i formulated my question. apologies!

Comment: @nikUoM: Have you looked into the **environment** diffs?

Comment: hey @Seamus. Sorry for taking so long -- but you're right, your hunch was correct. I stuck the calling of my scripts into separate shell scripts, containing the code referenced here - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cron-environment-and-cron-job-failures - and it worked! Thanks for your help.